# Linq Distinct Values with repeating values

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to ASP.net & I'm using MVC Code-First for my project.

```
Item Category SubCategory  
Item1 Cat1 Subcat1   
Item2 Cat2 Subcat2  
Item3 Cat3 Subcat1  
Item4 Cat2 Subcat2  
Item5 Cat1 Subcat2  
Item6 Cat2 Subcat3
```

I want to get a Distinct Categories & relevant Sub categories List from this table.
Can anyone help me , how to achieve this using, Linq query?
(It should be something similar to this.)

```
Cat1 =>Subcat1, Subcat2
Cat2 =>Subcat2,Subcat3
Cat3 =>Subcat1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `GroupBy` and `Distinct`

```
db.Cats
  .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
  .Select(x => new
   {
       Category = x.Key,
       SubCategories = x.Select(s => s.SubCategory).Distinct()
   });
```

Comment: A GroupBy alone might suffice in this case, since distinct was asked only for Category and that is implicitly achieved with grouping.